Faster Query to Track State changes in a Large Table
I have a table that tracks state changes of an entity with timestamps. The schema of the table is as follows:



entityid
userid
originalvalue
newvalue
changetime




255
101
Draft
Submitted
2023-11-28 12:10:56.389111


255
102
Submitted
Received
2023-12-04 10:30:02.776323


255
103
Received
Audited
2024-01-07 09:50:21.700231


255
104
Audited
Paid
2024-01-18 13:19:06.805542


255
105
Paid
In Progress
2024-02-04 12:10:58.670298


255
105
In Progress
Require Company Response
2024-02-04 12:44:03.201730


255
105
Require Company Response
In Progress
2024-05-19 11:37:08.419742


255
106
In Progress
Ready for primary registration
2024-05-19 11:37:53.641486


255
107
Ready for primary registration
In-session
2024-05-20 10:37:48.640948


255
107
In-session
Ready for primary registration
2024-05-20 11:45:44.560424


255
107
Ready for primary registration
In-session
2024-05-21 10:06:47.653381


255
107
In-session
Primary Registered
2024-06-06 15:29:22.813432


255
108
Primary Registered
Require Company Response
2024-06-09 14:21:12.664475


255
102
Require Company Response
In Progress
2024-06-24 08:28:55.994459



I want to compare the time it takes for the originalvalue to transition to the newvalue. For example, if the originalvalue is "Draft" and it becomes "Submitted", I need to find the corresponding newvalue in the next row and calculate the time between the originalvalue and newvalue changes.
To achieve this, I joined the table with itself on entityid where t1.newvalue = t2.originalvalue and t1.changetime <= t2.changetime:
  SELECT t1.entityid,
           t1.userid,
           t1.changetime as startStateTime
           t1.originalvalue as StartingState,
           t2.originalvalue as NextState,
           t2.changetime as nextStateTime
    FROM   table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table1 t2
               ON t1.entityid = t2.entityid
                  AND t1.newvalue = t2.originalvalue
                  and t1.changetime <= t2.changetime

However, this query sometimes results in duplicate rows where the same state transition appears multiple times with different timestamps. For example, the state "In Progress" appears multiple times, causing duplicates.



entityid
userid
StartStateTime
StartingState
NextState
NextStateTime




255
101
2023-11-28 12:10:56.389111
"Draft"
"Submitted"
2023-12-04 10:30:02.776323


255
102
2023-12-04 10:30:02.776323
"Submitted"
"Received"
2024-01-07 09:50:21.700231


255
103
2024-01-07 09:50:21.700231
"Received"
"Audited"
2024-01-18 13:19:06.805542


255
104
2024-01-18 13:19:06.805542
"Audited"
"Paid"
2024-02-04 12:10:58.670298


255
105
2024-02-04 12:10:58.670298
"Paid"
"In Progress"
2024-02-04 12:44:03.201730


255
105
2024-02-04 12:44:03.201730
"In Progress"
"Require Company Response"
2024-05-19 11:37:08.419742


255
105
2024-02-04 12:10:58.670298
"Paid"
"In Progress"
2024-05-19 11:37:53.641486


255
105
2024-05-19 11:37:08.419742
"Require Company Response"
"In Progress"
2024-05-19 11:37:53.641486


255
106
2024-05-19 11:37:53.641486
"In Progress"
"Ready for primary registration"
2024-05-20 10:37:48.640948


255
107
2024-05-20 10:37:48.640948
"Ready for primary registration"
"In-session"
2024-05-20 11:45:44.560424


255
106
2024-05-19 11:37:53.641486
"In Progress"
"Ready for primary registration"
2024-05-21 10:06:47.653381


255
107
2024-05-20 11:45:44.560424
"In-session"
"Ready for primary registration"
2024-05-21 10:06:47.653381


255
107
2024-05-20 10:37:48.640948
"Ready for primary registration"
"In-session"
2024-06-06 15:29:22.813432


255
107
2024-05-21 10:06:47.653381
"Ready for primary registration"
"In-session"
2024-06-06 15:29:22.813432


255
107
2024-06-06 15:29:22.813432
"In-session"
"Primary Registered"
2024-06-09 14:21:12.664475


255
105
2024-02-04 12:44:03.201730
"In Progress"
"Require Company Response"
2024-06-24 08:28:55.994459


255
108
2024-06-09 14:21:12.664475
"Primary Registered"
"Require Company Response"
2024-06-24 08:28:55.994459



To filter these duplicates, I used the ROW_NUMBER() window function:
what i did it user row number
   WITH NumberedStates AS (
    SELECT t1.entityid,
           t1.userid,
           t1.changetime AS startStateTime,
           t1.originalvalue AS StartingState,
           t2.originalvalue AS NextState,
           t2.changetime AS nextStateTime,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
               PARTITION BY t1.entityid, t1.originalvalue, t2.originalvalue
               ORDER BY t2.changetime ASC
           ) AS row_number
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table1 t2
        ON t1.entityid = t2.entityid
        AND t1.newvalue = t2.originalvalue
        AND t1.changetime <= t2.changetime
)
SELECT entityid, userid, startStateTime, StartingState, NextState, nextStateTime
FROM NumberedStates 
WHERE row_number = 1

Although this works, the table is very large (millions of rows), and the query is slow. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the desired result or optimize this approach?

Your originalvalue column is
denormed
and is perhaps a distraction.
What really matters is newvalue, along with
its associated timestamp (which is already normalized in your schema).
Do a quick GROUP BY changetime scan of the table
to view any rows HAVING COUNT(*) > 1.
If they're all unique, great.
Otherwise we can add a few microseconds of random fuzz,
or tack on a random GUID column to uniquify those timestamps.
Produce a new "report" relation with
PK
of (entityid, changetime), preserving all columns of interest
while discarding originalvalue.
Generate a new seq column with sequential integers from 1
up to the few million rows you have.
Create a compound index on (entityid, seq).
Now you're set up to do another (efficient!) self join.
In the ON clause it's trivially easy to predict the predecessor row:
we simply subtract 1.
The query completes quickly,
while the unique sequence number avoids duplicates.
Use EXPLAIN SELECT ... to verify the query plan is
exploiting that new index.
(Notice that we're using numbers that are sequential
within an entityid, not sequential across global timestamps.)

You can readily accomplish the same effect without allocating any
new DB storage, if you're willing to write a tiny amount of procedural code.
Simply ORDER BY entityid, changetime,
hang onto a prev row, and output the delta times as required.
Assuming that a given entity has a "small" number of state changes,
and that entityid is indexed, we can use this to quickly report
on entities of interest.
With an index on the timestamp column we'd also be able
to quickly identify the small collection of entities that
recently changed state.
